# How to solve dependencies problem in kivy Android?

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build a mobile app using kivy. When debugging in logcat I see:

```
File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 11, in <module>
2023-04-26 16:17:07.489 20274-20306 python                  org.testbarcode.barcode              I   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zbarcam'
```

I checked - zbarcam is specified in buildozer.spec :

```
requirements = android,
    kivy,
    libiconv,
    libzbar,
    Pillow,
    python3,
    pyzbar,
    xcamera,
    zbarcam
```

Also in the pip list, zbarcam can be found. To make sure, I tried different ways to install zbarcam. Installation via !sudo apt-get install zbar-tools was successful. Before that, I tried using kivy_garden. The assembly is carried out on google colab. The attempt to import from zbarcam import ZBarCam is successful.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would provide a minimized example with a reference wich line is  noted.